# PHP Dynamic Variables from an array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, variables, dynamic

I have a database that I am storing variable locations in. For instance, I have an array of leads, so I have a field called ID in the database, with the location of `$lead['@attributes']['Id']`. That is all set in the database.

The issue I am having is retrieving the value from the array I have.

What I have tried currently is something like this:

```
foreach($t AS $lead) {
    $newItem = [];
    foreach ($this->crm->fields AS $field) {
        $newItem[$field->name] = ${$field->location};
    }
}
```

This isn't working though. It gives me an error saying:

`Undefined variable: $lead['@attributes']['Id']`

BUT, if I do `echo $lead['@attributes']['Id']; die();`, it puts the ID on the page. What am I doing wrong?

> TLDR;

I need to create dynamic variables that I store in a database to get information from an array.

> Examples

This is the array I am trying to pull from:

```
array(6) {
  ["@attributes"]=>
  array(10) {
    ["Id"]=>
    string(7) "1086984"
    ["LeadTitle"]=>
    string(7) "1086984"
    ["CreateDate"]=>
    string(19) "03/11/2015 02:00:00"
    ["ModifyDate"]=>
    string(19) "04/13/2017 13:02:57"
    ["ActionCount"]=>
    string(2) "13"
    ["LogCount"]=>
    string(2) "13"
    ["ReminderCount"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["ReadOnly"]=>
    string(5) "false"
    ["Flagged"]=>
    string(5) "false"
    ["LastDistributionDate"]=>
    string(19) "01/01/0001 00:00:00"
  }
}
```

The database I have has the following in it:

```
ID | Name | Location

1  |  ID  | $lead['@attributes']['Id']
```

In the end, the array I get should look as follows:

```
array(10) {
  ["ID"]=>
  string(7) "1086984"
}
```

## EDIT 1

I am getting an XML file from a platform, via cURL. I am taking that XML file, running it through `simplexml_load_string()`, then `json_encode()` and `json_decode()`, giving me an array in the end.

I then also have a database, with a list of field names, and the locations in the array I created from the XML file. I am then cycling through the database of fields, and saving the XML file, in a better parsed way, to the database. I do this once every 5 minutes on the updated information. I am not the one generating the XML file, nor do I normally save information in the way that I am having to. I understand this probably isn't the best way to do it, but it is for internal use only, no one outside my company even is going to have access to the website we are making.

## EDIT 2/UPDATE 1

I RAN INTO ANOTHER ROADBLOCK. They have a item called "fields", with an array of fields in it.

[image: fields example]

The problem is, everything is an "attribute" on them. They are, for example, address, email, first name, last name, etc. How would I cycle through that to get the correct data? Any ideas?

This issue also exists with 3 other objects. Actions and Logs, lots of logs...

Comment: This is a horrible way to store data, you should change to something like a path `lead.attributes.id` or some other strategy.  The only was to do it your way is `eval("\$newItem[{$field->name}] = {$field->location};");`

Comment: AbraCadaver What would you suggest? This is only for parsing data. A platform we use gives us an XML file, and we parse it. To make it easy to update, we want to make it all dynamic using a MySQL database to get the information from the XML array we generate. We parse it, and then save it to a table in our MySQL database.

Comment: `Undefined variable: $lead['@attributes']['Id']` means, it's treating it as a string, not object/array. Sooo... @AbraCadaver's eval suggestion, do it ;)

Comment: Problem, the code `eval("\$newItem[{$field->name}] = {$field->location};");` gives me this error: `Use of undefined constant ID - assumed 'ID'`

Comment: Why not try `eval()` on just the `$field->location` portion? Would that not work?

Comment: I am using simpleXML to do it, the problem becomes each lead has different information, like some items are missing, and some items are there. I am parsing it using SimpleXML, then JSON encoding it, then JSON decoding it, since the depth it goes is up to 10 items deep. (ie, lead.campaign.fields.campaign.source.attributes...). It is nasty XML.

Comment: I asked the platform why they can't just dump it as JSON, it would make everyones lives so much easier. They said: "No.", bluntly too, literally just that in an email...

Comment: Designing your data model so that it needs to know where your code is storing its data is a bad idea IMO; the database shouldn't care what your controller code does.

Comment: @amphetamachine do you know of a way for me to parse the whole XML file, and save it in a better way to a database? I am doing it the way I know how to at this point. I am at a roadblock due to the difficulties I have been having with the XML we are getting. I hate it personally, I have requested NUMEROUS times that they just give us a JSON dump of it. More stupid that the XML, they use JSON for their interface.... Why... why can't they give us access to the JSON version, I will never understand.

Comment: @BrianLogan Store as text, and leave the interpretation to the controller layer (i.e. your code). What you **don't** want to have happen is your schema being broken because the JSON file updates its format.

I know you're using MySQL, but PostgreSQL has JSON data types, so you can query based on attribute values in the JSONified object.

Comment: @AbraCadaver are you on twitter or anything? I would like to message you privately with more information about the code and everything. Could you add me by chance? i'm darkgoldblade on twitter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid use of eval(), you could store your data in your database like this:

```
ID | Name | Location

1  |  ID  | @attributes.Id
```

The data in your database doesn't need to know the name of your PHP variable.

```
foreach($t AS $lead) {
    $newItem = [];
    foreach ($this->crm->fields AS $field) {
        list($f1, $f2) = explode('.', $field->location);
        $newItem[$field->name] = $lead[$f1][$f2];
    }
}
```

Re your update:

I honestly would not use the database to encode your field mappings. I'd define the field mappings in your PHP script.

You'll have to define special-case loops for your Fields, Actions, and Logs.

I don't envy you. I have done apps like this where I had to accept data from another department, formatted in some ill-defined way. In my case, I was sent an Excel spreadsheet, and I wrote code to parse it and get the data out of it that I needed. But the department who send the spreadsheet changed the format every week, so I had to recode my parsing routine. I tried telling them, "decide on the format for the spreadsheet and keep it the same every week." They ignored my request and continued making it differently every time. Then my contract was up and I left, knowing they would break it the week after I left.

Comment: Can you see my update 2/edit 2 or whatever on the post. having another problem, and if there is something I could do easily to fix it, I would love to just do it that way instead. Also, what would happen if I need to go 4 deep? Do I need t code the `[$f1][$f2][$f3]..` depending on how many `.` there are?

Comment: Yeah, the hard part is that they don't change it, but we have multiple clients using the same platform, but different data/formatting in the XML because of that. Hence why I was looking to do something like the dynamic variables. I sent you a connect request on LinkedIn, so I could message you directly. Is that okay with you?

Comment: I'm happy to make your acquaintence, but I have limits to the amount of time I can do one-on-one help. I like to answer questions on Stack Overflow and Quora because doing it in public like this can help many other readers.